# Wordpress Multisite Error - After change ip to domain

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to make my development site to be live with my domain. So I change the ip development with the domain.

after making change, my website unable to open:

```
 Access forbidden!
    You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected.

    If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

    Error 403
    ddmc.co.id
    Apache/2.4.39 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1b PHP/7.3.4
```

Server: On premise server
web server: xampp

**WP_OPTION**

```
siteurl: ddmc.co.id
home: ddmc.co.id
```

**WP_SITE**

```
domain: ddmc.co.id
path: /
```

**WP_SITEMETA**

```
siteurl: ddmc.co.id
```

**WP_BLOGS**

```
domain: ddmc.co.id path:/
domain: ddmc.co.id path:/id/
```

**wp-config.php**

```
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'ddmc.co.id');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE','/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT', 1);
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '512M');
```

**htaccess**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

**htpd-vhosts**

```
<Directory "c:/xampp/htdocs/hcml">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I Appreciate for your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
```

To:

```
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
```